# Ellipsis notation in C#?

Tags: c#, variadic-functions, ellipsis

Where can I get info about implementing my own methods that have the ellipsis notation,

e.g.

```
static void my_printf(char* format, ...) { }
```

Also is that called ellipsis notation or is there a fancier name?

Comment: The fancy name is "variadic functions".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have a look at the [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

Answer (score 40):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params:

> By using the **`params`** keyword, you can specify a method parameter that
>   takes a variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified
>   in the parameter declaration or an array of arguments of the specified
>   type. You also can send no arguments. If you send no arguments, the
>   length of the params list is zero.

```
static void MyPrintf(string format, params object[] args) { }

...

MyPrintf(1, 'a', "test");
```